# How can I print a2ps a file --portrait without being all squished?

Tags: printing, a2ps

I installed a2ps for printing but the output is landscaped.

I tried using --portrait which 'kinda' worked... but didn't.  The orientation was switched 90' but it's only 50% of the width and the text is tiny.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short answer

Use `-1` instead of `--portrait`.

#### Slightly longer answer

By default `a2ps` tries to put 2 pages on each sheet, this works best side-by-side and landscape, even if you rotate the page `a2ps` still tries to insert 2 pages. The answer is to give `a2ps` the `-1` switch which instructs it to only have 1 page per sheet (`3-9` are also valid number of pages).